# Size at a distance

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

While on the ground I saw a shape like a small match box shape floating just above a cloud deck at approximately 2000 feet (the object was in the clear but then drifted above the deck) I was looking up at about a 50 degree angle.  At arms length it was about 1.5 inches long, 1 inch wide and 1/4 inch thick. Range was maybe 1 mile.

Can you tell me the size of the object?  My math is way old now, like me. I was a young professional  pilot at the time, I believe my parameters are pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

If the distance to the object is $D$, then trigonometry tells us
$$
\sin 50^\circ = \frac{2000}{D}
$$
so
$$
D = \frac{2000}{\sin 50^\circ} \approx 2610 \text{ feet}
$$
When you measure the object with your fingers at arm's length, you need to scale by $D / d$ to get the actual length, where $d$ is the length of your arm.
I don't know the length of your arm, but as a rough estimate, let's say it is $28$ inches.  In this case,
\begin{align*}
1.5 \text{ in} \cdot \frac{2610 \text{ ft}}{28 \text{ in}} &\approx 140 \text{ ft} \\
1.0 \text{ in} \cdot \frac{2610 \text{ ft}}{28 \text{ in}} &\approx 93 \text{ ft} \\
1/4 \text{ in} \cdot \frac{2610 \text{ ft}}{28 \text{ in}} &\approx 23 \text{ ft} \\
\end{align*}

So perhaps the object was $140 \times 93 \times 23$ feet.
There's a lot of room for error here, so don't take the exact values too seriously.